# Massive import with CSV file

Tags: scripting, import, csv

I have exported game archive with all objects. I also have CSV file with all their details, such as model name, location, rotation (XYZW). How do I import CSV file, and make blender read it and put all objects on the places? 
Ps. Z rotation axis must be multiplied to '-1'.

Comment: @batFINGER, Hi. Thanks for the reply. Your code helps me but didn't solve my problem. FBX importing doesn't have a location and rotation, unlike UV spheres in your example. I see axis_forward and axis_up in FBX importing example, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @batFINGER, I practised little more and successfully assigned location to object. But a question about rotation and scale is still teasing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after @batFINGER `s examples, I wrote my example. The code is 'Ugly' but in the other hand, it's working

```
import bpy
import csv

csvfile = "yourfiledirectory\file.csv"
suffix = '.fbx'
with open(csvfile) as csvfile:
    csvread = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate (csvread):
        if i==0: continue
        filename = row[0]
        loc_x = row[1]
        loc_y = row[2]
        loc_z = row[3]
        scale_x  = row[4]
        scale_y  = row[5]
        scale_z  = row[6]
        rot_x = row[7]
        rot_y = row[8]
        rot_z = row[9]
        rot_z = float(rot_z)*-1
        rot_w = row[10]
        dir = "directory where your files are"
        bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = dir )
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(float(loc_x), float(loc_y), float(loc_z)))
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(float(scale_x), float(scale_y), float(scale_z)))
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            a = obj.name
            print(a)
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[a]
            bpy.context.object.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
            bpy.context.object.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
            bpy.context.object.rotation_quaternion[0] = float(rot_w)
            bpy.context.object.rotation_quaternion[1] = float(rot_x)
            bpy.context.object.rotation_quaternion[2] = float(rot_y)
            bpy.context.object.rotation_quaternion[3] = float(rot_z)
```

Comment: Instead fo `loc_x = row[1]` and the next two lines, use something like `loc = [float(x) for x in row[1:4]]`. Then you can replace the `bpy.ops.transform.translate` line with `bpy.context.object.location = loc`.

Also, in your loop you can just directly assign to `obj.rotation_mode` and `obj.rotation_quaternion`, there is no need to set the active object.