# Keyframing specified object location at frame from csv data

Tags: python, animation, csv

I've been trying animate a large amount of objects based on location and frame data from an excel sheet. So far I've read through a dozen different threads both here and other forums, but I'm just not able to understand how to do it. My only previous coding experience is only a small amount of html/css, so having a slightly hard time wrapping my head around this.

[image]

```
Object_id,X-Loc,Y-Loc,Z-Loc,Frame
Sphere_01,0,0,0,1
Sphere_01,6,0,0,25
Sphere_01,6,-6,0,40
,,,,
Cube_01,3,3,0,1
Cube_01,3,3,10,25
Cube_01,3,3,0,40
Cube_01,10,3,0,60
```

This is what I use to test on. The goal is to have the script select each object, set its location at a specified frame and keyframe it. So that I can then manually tweak the transition between them if needed.

So far this is the code I have so far, [partially copied from here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119865/massive-import-with-csv-file) And i somewhat understand what it does, I think, it at least moves the sphere in the scene.

```
import bpy
import csv

csvfile = open('FilePath/Sphere_Anim.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for i, row in enumerate (readcsv):
    if i==0: continue
    obname = row[0]
    loc = [float(x) for x in row[1:4]]
    frame = row[4]

    bpy.context.object.location = loc
```

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data to blender edits.**

- Get the scene object `ob` by name. Skip if not present in scene.
- Add location keyframes at each frame  using

  ```
  ob.keyframe_insert("location", frame)
  ```

  [Read the docs:](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=keyframe_insert#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert)

Edited script.

```
import bpy
import csv

scene = bpy.context.scene    

csvfile = open('FilePath/Sphere_Anim.csv')
readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for i, row in enumerate(readcsv):
    if i == 0: 
        continue
    obname = row[0]
    # get the object
    ob = scene.objects.get(obname)
    if not ob:
        continue
    loc = [float(x) for x in row[1:4]]
    # set location
    ob.location = loc # local
    #ob.matrix_world.translation = loc # global
    frame = int(row[4])
    # insert all location keyframes  
    ob.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frame)
```

Related.

[Fast keyframe insertion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111644/fast-keyframe-insertion)

Comment: Oh, wow, this seems to work perfectly :) Thanks for the links too, seems I've got a lot to read up on:)