# "Animated vector" multiple object moves from CSV with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, vector, csv

Newby question for the Anination Nodes experts if I may...

Trying to visualise time-sequence data for a series of objects that move in X & Y. I have used some of the great answers here to get close but I have 2 problems;

1. I can extract the new destination from a line and move the object but it just jumps rather than smoothly animated from where it was last to where it is moving to. Tried to hack it with a Annimate vector node but cant loop the Result vector back to the Start vector.
2. I can not convice the extacted object_ID to connect to the object connector of the "object Transforms Output" node.

Sure what I have done so far will make you cringe but hey ho, just learning. Eventual data will have ~500  Object ID's and 5000 odd moves for each one so automating this would be awesome.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

[image: Screen shot of nodetree]

Comment: Do u want to traverse smoothly b/w bunch of points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Vector List from csv. Then traverse through points using `Mix Vector List`.

[image]

Comment: perfect. You're a star.

Comment: Pushing my luck a little here but .....  How do I now do this concurrently for multiple objects where the object id is in the line of text?

Comment: Can u explain bit more? What do u mean by object id?

Comment: Sorry .....In my final dataset I will have ~500 objects that move around an XY plane independently and concurrently.

Comment: For each cycle of a simulation, I will report the current position of each device. So my dataset will have 4 fields; Simulation_Cycle,DeviceID,X,Y. Every 50 frames I will select the next simulation cycle and set a new destination for each blender object that represents one of the devices. The devices move in a smooth animation to the new destination over the 50 frames until the next update. Any clues would really help, thanks a lot.

Comment: I think creating one more loop for every object would be enough. can u show me a how a sample  dataset looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this python script on the forum and it works really well to do exactly what I was after so thought I should share.
[Keyframing specified object location at frame from csv data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133792/keyframing-specified-object-location-at-frame-from-csv-data)

Thanks @HariSreedhar for the help